# Extract GPX data with php, foreach only first result

Tags: php, file, foreach, gpx

i`m tring to extract data from a gpx file and and save it in mysql with php and i write this:

```
 $gpx = simplexml_load_file('uploads/unzip/'.$gpsfile.'/'.$gpxfile.'.gpx');
     foreach ($gpx->trk->trkseg->trkpt as $trkpt) {
         $lat = (string) $trkpt['lat'];
         $lon = (string) $trkpt['lon'];
         $name = (string) $gpx->trk->name;
         $desc = (string) $gpx->trk->desc;
         echo $lat;
         echo $lon;
         echo $desc;
       }
```

but foreach function it's show me only the first set of trkpt coordonates. I need to return all trk section with all trkpt coordonates.

file have multiple trk section like this:

```
    <trk>
      <name>test/name>
      <cmt>-</cmt>
      <desc>test</desc>
      <src>20--</src>
      <trkseg>
        <trkpt lat="44.867687980932203" lon="28.309019488759262">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.867702520087697" lon="28.308913064206525">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.867722086992117" lon="28.308743677250508">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.874962661538952" lon="28.311624759622379">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.87496253919776" lon="28.311625616880288">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.874914089738589" lon="28.311942660248032">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.874914070326035" lon="28.311942768555909">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.867687980932203" lon="28.309019488759262">
        </trkpt>
      </trkseg>
    </trk>
<trk>
      <name>test/name>
      <cmt>-</cmt>
      <desc>test</desc>
      <src>20--</src>
      <trkseg>
        <trkpt lat="44.867687980932203" lon="28.309019488759262">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.867702520087697" lon="28.308913064206525">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.867722086992117" lon="28.308743677250508">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.874962661538952" lon="28.311624759622379">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.87496253919776" lon="28.311625616880288">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.874914089738589" lon="28.311942660248032">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.874914070326035" lon="28.311942768555909">
        </trkpt>
        <trkpt lat="44.867687980932203" lon="28.309019488759262">
        </trkpt>
      </trkseg>
    </trk>
```

Comment: Aren't you supposed to `foreach ($gpx->trk` only? And then add the rest of the path to the variable in the loop? Otherwise you won't get the second set of Gps data. And you would need a subloop to loop the trkpt.

Comment: i do that but now it's get me only 12 sets of coordonates but i have much more in file

Comment: when i  var_dump ($gpx); i get all data.

Comment: Personally, I like my [iterable GPX Reader](https://github.com/MarkBaker/GeneratorFunctionExamples/tree/master/GpxTracker/classes/src/GpxReader) that demonstrates PHP's `yield`